# How to create smooth motion for a mouse follower along a predefined path?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to make a tracing game. I want my circle to follow the path as the user traces the letter (path of the letter). The user can not go back to the area which is already traced

```
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    var i: Number;
    var size: int = 80;
    var down: Boolean = false;
    var up: Boolean = true;
    var inside: Boolean = true;
    var outside: Boolean = true;
    var circle: Shape = new Shape();

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup);
    char.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);

    function loop(e: Event) {
if (down == true) {
    // Checks if mouse pointer is on path i.e 'S' alphabet
    if (s.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, true)) {
        inside = true;
        outside = true;

        var point: Point = maskobj.globalToLocal(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY));
        var point2: Point = new Point();

        //Checks if mouse pointer is completely outside of drawn area
        for (i = 0; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += (2 * Math.PI) / 10) {
            point2.x = stage.mouseX + (size / 3) * Math.cos(i);
            point2.y = stage.mouseY + (size / 3) * Math.sin(i);
            if ((maskobj.hitTestPoint(point2.x, point2.y, true))) {
                outside = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        //Checks if mouse pointer is completely inside drawn area
        for (i = 0; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += (2 * Math.PI) / 10) {
            point2.x = stage.mouseX + (size / 3) * Math.cos(i);
            point2.y = stage.mouseY + (size / 3) * Math.sin(i);

            if (!(maskobj.hitTestPoint(point2.x, point2.y, true))) {
                inside = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        //Character will be moved only if mouse position not to far from current position
        if (outside == false) {
            if (inside == false) {
                //Increases drawn area by drawing a circle shape in 'maskobj' MovieClip

                circle.graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff);
                circle.graphics.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, size);
                circle.graphics.endFill();
                maskobj.addChild(circle);

                //Moves character to new position
                char.x = stage.mouseX;
                char.y = stage.mouseY;
            }
        }
    }
}
    }

    function mouseup(e: MouseEvent): void {
up = true;
down = false;
    }

    function mousedown(e: MouseEvent): void {
down = true;
up = false;
    }
```

[image]
[image]

When I trace the path,the motion is not smooth. Can someone please suggest a way to make the motion smooth OR suggest another way to achieve the same. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I did understand it good, your problem is that the red circle moves with somehow vibration and not smooth. you can set it to tween between some count of dots on the path. it should decrease the vibration. if it didn't work, should solve it by a better way.

Comment: if it didn't work, probably should use a math that makes a smooth way between dots. like the pen tool.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a drawing game before that allowed the user to draw a path.

Not sure why Wicked's answer was down-voted, as the first thing you need to do is to use the highest frame rate that you can get away with. The higher the frame rate, the smoother your curve.

I see that your code draws a circle at the current position if the conditions are met. It might be better to draw a line from the last point.x/point.y to the current one instead of just a circle, so that you don't have any holes in your path.

I couldn't get around the fact that the line was jagged (a series of straight lines) as it was being drawn, but as soon as the user lifted their finger I was able to take the points along the line they had drawn and replace them with a smooth bezier Path (a series of simple bezier curves), which worked well. You could also do this on-the-fly once you have 3 points (you need 3 points to draw a curve).

[Here is a good reference](http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/) on how to achieve this, with theory and code samples. See further down the page for bezier paths. You'll need to convert to AS3, but it shouldn't be difficult.

Another tip is to do as little calculation as possible within the ENTER_FRAME. You could pre-calculate the two values used by your loops (2 * Math.PI) and ((2 * Math.PI) / 10) as these are constants. You could also calculate (size/3) once at the top of the function, and especially pre-calculate the 10 values for Math.sin(i) and Math.cos(i) and store them in an Array (basically a LUT - Look Up Table) as these are the heaviest math ops you're doing.

My final tip is that your code doesn't check if the point being drawn is very close to the last point that was drawn. I would recommend you do this, and only draw a point after the mouse has moved a minimum distance (e.g. 2 pixels). Otherwise you could get the mouse sitting still in one spot and your code is drawing circle upon circle on top of itself needlessly.

Comment: What makes you think this is a performance issue? Did you run this through a profiler to see that this is a performance issue? I very much doubt that using a look up table will help smooth out the motion.

Comment: The main part of my answer is not performance related (regarding converting dots to lines, and straight lines to curves). There are some extra tips to improving performance, which can only help achieving better performance and smoother lines.

Answer (score -1):

Try increasing the FPS in your document to atleast double what you currently have
Modify>Document...>Frame Rate